# unable to convert .htaccess to web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, web-config

For this pc of code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i am using

```
<rule name="rule 1A" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="."  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php"  />
</rule>
```

but not work... why ?

Answer (score 0):

This config is solved my problem

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="DeduplicateSlashes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(.*)//(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="CleanRouting" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="?id={R:0}&amp;{QUERY_STRING}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- Double escaping is needed for URLs with '+', e.g. for the account page for a username with a space. -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>

 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```